Line Chart for Multiple Projects, Calculated from 1 Month Before Each Project's Start as 100
I want to create a Power BI accumulated line chart with multiple lines that every time should show 4 lines (1 for the project and 3 for benchmarks), and all calculated as 100 from 1 month before the project's start month only (Benchmarks will follow the project start month too).
e.g. (1)
If Project A starts in Jan 2021
The value for Project A & all other 3 Benchmarks in DEC 2020 should be set at 100
And the subsequent months would be calculated as follows:

Jan 2021  =  100 *  (1 + Jan 2021 Return rate/ 100)
Feb 2021  =  Jan 2021 Result *  (1 + Feb 2021 Return rate / 100)
Mar 2021  =  Feb 2021 Result *  (1 + Mar 2021 Return rate / 100)
etc..

e.g. (2)
If the Project B is start from Sep 2023
The value for Project B & all other 3 Benchmarks in Aug 2023 should be set at 100

I've search & tried so many DAX, but all fail to meet below requirement.

Benchmark 's Total returns on $100 USD:
Set the starting point for benchmark start from selected portfolio as 100 from one month before each portfolio's start month.

Attached a sample PBIX file and the outcome of the line chart for your reference.
Thanks in advance!
Expected Outcome
Current FAIL model
Sample Power BI Model

Measure =

VAR first_date = CALCULATE(MIN('Data'[Date]),ALLSELECTED('Data'))
VAR last_date = MAX('Data'[Date])
VAR mandate = MAX('Data'[Name])
VAR FilteredTable =
FILTER(
ALL('Data'),
'Data'[Date] <= last_date &&
MONTH('Data'[Date]) = MONTH(last_date) &&
'Data'[Name] = mandate
)
VAR FilteredTable_2 =
FILTER(
ALL('Data'),
'Data'[Date] <= last_date &&
'Data'[Date]> first_date &&
'Data'[Name] = mandate
)


VAR HasData = NOT(ISBLANK(SUMX(FilteredTable, 'Data'[Mothly Return (%)])))
RETURN
IF(HasData,
IF(MIN('Data'[Date])=first_date,100,
100*PRODUCTX(FilteredTable_2,1+[Mothly Return (%)]/100)
)
,BLANK()
)

